# How do we add DefaultRequestVersion on an HttpClient object in Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, httpclient

I have been trying a way to add the Http Version as 1.0 in Powershell to my HttpClient Object.

```
  function Post-JSONData
    {
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] [String] $JSONPayload,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] [String] $ObjectClass,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] [String] $APIUrl,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)] [String] $ProxyUrl
    )
    
    #Try{
    
        If($JSONPayload.StartsWith("[") -eq $false -and  $JSONPayload.EndsWith("]") -eq $false)
            { $JSONPayload = "[" + $JSONPayload + "]" }
        
        [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;
    
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Net.Http
    
        $WebHandler = New-Object  System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler
        $WebHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = $false;
    
        
        If($ProxyUrl)
        {
            $WebProxy = New-Object System.Net.WebProxy($ProxyUrl)
            $WebHandler.Proxy = $WebProxy
        }
    
    
    
        $HttpClient = New-Object System.Net.Http.HttpClient($WebHandler)
        **$HttpClient.DefaultRequestVersion = [System.Net.HttpVersion]::Version10**
        $HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept","*/*");
        $HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        $HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection","keep-alive");
        $HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Class",$ObjectClass);
    
    
        $HttpClient.Timeout = New-Object System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 90);
    
        $HttpJSONPayload = New-Object System.Net.Http.StringContent($JSONPayload.ToString(), [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8, "application/json")
        $HttpJSONPayload.Headers.ContentEncoding.Add("gzip")
        $HttpJSONPayload.Headers.ContentEncoding.Add("deflate")
        $HttpJSONPayload.Headers.ContentEncoding.Add("br")
        
        $ResponsePayload = $HttpClient.PostAsync([Uri] $APIUrl,$HttpJSONPayload)
```

I am able to add the DefaultRequestHeader Parameters but I believe there is some issue with the format for DefaultRequestVersion.

I am unable to find documentation online either for the same.

Update: I am using Powershell V4.0 so $HttpClient.DefaultRequestVersion = [System.Net.HttpVersion]::Version10 is giving the following error:

The property 'DefaultRequestVersion' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.

Comment: What do you mean there is a issue?  What exactly is not working? IS there a Error? (If so please post the error)

Comment: There is an error when it sends the Post request. My query is how do I Set DefaultRequestVersion for an HttpClient object in powershell.

Answer (score 3):

The `DefaultRequestVersion` property is not a list, but a single [`HttpVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpversion?view=netframework-4.5.1) value.

To default to `HTTP 1.0`, assign it like this:

```
$HttpClient.DefaultRequestVersion = [System.Net.HttpVersion]::Version10
```

Beware that the `DefaultRequestVersion` property was only introduced in .NET Core 3.0, so the earliest version of PowerShell with this property exposed is [PowerShell 7.0.0](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v7.0.0)

---

For PowerShell 4.0, you can change your code slightly to support overriding the HTTP Version by manually crafting the request and calling `SendAsync()` directly (instead of `PostAsync()`):

Take this line:

```
$ResponsePayload = $HttpClient.PostAsync([Uri] $APIUrl,$HttpJSONPayload)
```

... and replace it with:

```
# Manually craft the request message and overwrite the version
$RequestPayload = New-Object System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage @([System.Net.Http.HttpMethod]::Post, [uri]$APIUrl)
$RequestPayload.Version = '1.0'
$RequestPayload.Content = $HttpJSONPayload

# Pass the crafted message directly to SendAsync()
$ResponsePayload = $HttpClient.SendAsync($RequestPayload)
```

Comment: Got the following Error : The property 'DefaultRequestVersion' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.

Comment: @Aman But `$HttpClient = New-Object System.Net.Http.HttpClient($WebHandler)` succeeds? That's odd. What version of PowerShell are you using

Comment: Yes, that was my contention as well. I am using Powershell 4.0

Comment: @Aman That explains, `DefaultRequestVersion` was only introduced in .NET Core 3.0, so you'll have to use PowerShell 7 to take advantage

Comment: Is there any other method to set this in Powershell 4.0?

Comment: @Aman The only other option is to explicitly set the version on the individual `HttpRequestMessage` instances, so it depends a bit on how you're using the `HttpClient` - can you update your post with what you're ultimately trying to achieve or do with the resulting client object?

Comment: @Aman Please avoid posting more than a single line of code in comments, it's impossible to format well. Update your original post instead :)

Comment: @Aman Cheers, I've updated the answer to show how you can achieve what you need